# appending child dives to HTML view inside an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do this:
I have an array of objects inside `Angular` `controller` and i want to write a directive that for each members of that array, creates a div element in the HTML view and if new items cames to array, view updates automatically and if an item removed, HTML updates too. i do this:

this is my controller:

```
app.controller("timelineCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.arr={};
         .
         .
         .
}
```

this is my directive:

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div> Hello {{arrayItem}} </div>',

        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            //here i know that i have to write some code 
            // i have to watch any changes in array and compile it to HTML view
        }
    };
});
```

this is my view:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="timelineCtrl">
     <hello-world></hello-world>
</div
```

i know i have to write some code inside `link` property of directive, but i can't do this. i have to create a loop for that array and check values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has `ng-repeat` directive to display items form arrays.
For your purposes, you can create a directive responsible for single item logic and use `ng-repeat` to render these items. Ng repeat will take care about added or removed items from array:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="timelineCtrl">
    <hello-world ng-repeat="arrayItem in arr" array-item="arrayItem"></hello-world>
</div
```

To propagate item data into directive, you should do this config

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<div> Hello {{arrayItem}} </div>',
    scope: {
       arrayItem: '=' // this means that scope value should be taken from attribute with corresponding name
    },

    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        // your logic with single arrayItem
        // item available as $scope.arrayItem
    }
  };
});
```

You can learn more about how it works in the angular docs, on [that page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) see "scope" section

Comment: can you complete link section? it doesn't work for me

Comment: What do you expect? Look at [fiddle with my code](http://jsfiddle.net/27LpcosL/), there are three items in a list

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this?
itterate over the array with ng-repeat will handle new and deleted items. (you wdont need to do anything in the link function)

```
 app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: true,
            scope:{
                   arrayItem: '=ngModel'
              },
        template: '<div> Hello {{arrayItem}} </div>',

    };
});


<div class="row" ng-controller="timelineCtrl">
     <hello-world ng-repeat="arrayItem in arr" ng-model="arrayItem"></hello-world>
</div>
```